# perl not able to recognize perforce commands

Tags: perl, perforce

I am trying to write perl program to make changes in Perforce. 
When I run Perforce commands using P4 from the command line, those work fine but when I write "Use P4" in a perl program, it is not able to identify the P4 class. 
Is there any configuration I might be missing?

P.S> -Since, it is working fine from a command line, I am assuming that my path is set correctly.

This is the error which I am getting:
Can't locate object method "new" via package "P4" (perhaps you forgot to load "P4"?) at perlP4.pl line 5.

This is my program:

```
use strict;
push ( @INC,"C:\Program Files\Perforce");
use lib "C:\Program Files\Perforce";
use P4; # a p4perl module
my $p4 = new P4;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try single quotes? `use lib 'C:\Program Files\Perforce';`

Comment: No, it is still not working. In majority of the programs, I have seen they straight away use the line:
Use P4 and then use it. 

Something like this:
    use strict;
    use P4;
    my $p4 = new P4;

Comment: Where did you put the `P4` module? I wonder if it does exist in `C:\Program Files\Perforce`. `p4.exe` may be there but not `P4Perl`.

Comment: I have following exe files in C:\Program Files\Perforce:
p4.exe
p4v.exe
p4merge.exe
p4admin.exe
assistant.exe

Did I miss P4Perl.exe? From where can I get it?

Also, how are P4 commands then working on command line.

Comment: check out http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4perlnotes.txt and follow the install guide.

Answer (score 1):

P4 module is stored in a file P4.pm. Try to find this module in your system to see it is installed or not.

If it is not installed, then please install it first.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html

Comment: Dead link as of 11/28/2018

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Perforce in a while, so I maybe out of date here:

The P4 module requires the Perforce C++ API library to be used, and there is quite a bit of compiled C programming with the P4 module. With Windows, much of this is already compiled (and I see you're using Windows).

Read the installation directions **very carefully**. Make sure you have the API libraries installed as well as the P4 module (and all of its sub-modules) installed. Since `use P4;` itself doesn't throw an error, I am assuming that the Perl portion of the P4 module is installed. The problem is communicating with the P4 C++ API.

The `sub new` subroutine isn't in the `P4.pm` module, but is part of the `P4.xs` XS package. If you have `P4.pm` installed, but you don't have the API setup correctly, you will get the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

On your command prompt run the following:

```
    perl -MP4 -e "print P4::Identify()"
```

If you have not installed the p4perl module you will see:

```
Can't locate P4.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/....
.... (snip) ....
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```